# Visual studio - Start without debugging - localhost connected but doesn't open it in a browser

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I opened my older project after the last VS update and now when I use "Start without debugging", IIS Express shows that it's connected to the localhost but it doesn't actually open the site in a browser.

[localhost connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW2L6.png)

Note: When I type the localhost address in the browser manually, the site works. Also, when I start with Debugging, it works normally (automatically) opens the browser with the site.

Everything worked fine before the update, so I just rebuilt the solution. I Don't want to screw up VS settings.

[Not sure if that's the right settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DfIQ.png)

Any idea what could be wrong, please? Or what else info would help to identify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are three methods please try one by one:

1. Set the startup option in vs to browser instead of project.
2. Open the launchSettings.json file under the project (the file is located in the Properties folder). Change the "lauchBrowser" option to true.
3. Set the startup default browser to another browser on your computer.